# Ignore Variables in Array

Tags: php, forms, variables

I have a series of variables being called to create a larger array.

```
$modelfinal = "$model0, $model1, $model2, $model3, $model4";
```

How do I ignore the one that are empty in $modelfinal?

Comment: Combine http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php, you can do it! That's assuming that you actually do want to merge arrays, and the example you have up there is just your way of depicting that...you are dealing with arrays, right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm merging the variables into one larger variable.

Comment: From what I see here you're concatenating the five `$model`s into `$modelfinal`.

Comment: Correct @rink.attendant.6 , however, I want to ignore the empty values.

Comment: It should probably be said:  if you were using arrays like a real programmer, you probably wouldn't even have to worry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you have kept track of all of the arrays that you may need to merge within a single array:

```
$modelfinal = array();

foreach($array_of_all_arrays as $value) {
    if(!empty($arr)) {
        $modelfinal[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($modelfinal);
```

If you know the names of each `$modelx` and they are constant each time the page is called, just add them to the total array with:

```
$array_of_all_arrays[] = $modelx;
```

where `$modelx` is the actual model variable. You would add each model variable individually. Obviously, rename that array to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: How do I actually associated $model1, $model,2, etc with it?

Comment: Where are those variables coming from?

Comment: They're being called from a form:

Comment: $model0 = $_REQUEST['model0_is_checked']; $model1 = $_REQUEST['model1_is_checked']; ... and so on.

Comment: Do I assign $array_of_all_arrays like so? $modelsub[] = $model0;
$modelsub[] = $model1;
$modelsub[] = $model2;
$modelsub[] = $model3;
$modelsub[] = $model4;  (Obviously, I've renamed it to $modelsub

Comment: Yep, go ahead and try it out and see what happens.

Comment: I keep getting: unexpected T_AS, expecting ';' on the for line.

Comment: $model0 = $_REQUEST['model0_is_checked'];
$model1 = $_REQUEST['model1_is_checked'];
$model2 = $_REQUEST['model2_is_checked'];  AND THEN $modelsub[] = $model0;
$modelsub[] = $model1;
$modelsub[] = $model2; AND THEN $modelfinal = array();

for($modelsub as $arr) {
    if(!empty($arr)) {
        $modelfinal = array_merge($modelfinal, $arr);
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, I realize I typo'd. Its a foreach loop, not a for loop. Try it with a foreach loop. (I have updated the code snippet)

Comment: I get this: PHP Warning:  array_merge() [<a href='function.array-merge'>function.array-merge</a>]: Argument #1 is not an array in /home/f142468/public_html/auto-search/reno/send_mail.php on line 36

Comment: Very strange, but try my edit. I manually casted the first argument to an array, although it should already be an array.

Comment: Please see http://codepad.org/M8VWHMuv for a working example. Compare to this code to make sure there are no other typos/etc.

Comment: I noticed you've got array declarations at the top... how would I change $model0=$_REQUEST['model0_is_checked']; to an array?

Comment: Hold on, what data type is `$_REQUEST['model0_is_checked']`?

Comment: It's pulling data from a form, assigning it a value if the box is checked, or just "" if it isn't.

Comment: I assumed the values were arrays (that's what I was trying to ask from the beginning. The current solution should be fine (I have edited the post again)

Comment: Do I have to convert the values to an array?

Comment: No, leave the assignment code as it was before. (`$model0 = $_REQUEST['model0_is_checked']`) is fine.

Comment: Well the error is gone, but All I get is "Array" as the output.

Comment: `print_r()` should output the contents of the array. Are you using `print_r()`, and not `echo`?

Comment: Yep: $modelfinal = array();

foreach($array_of_all_arrays as $value) {
    if(!empty($arr)) {
        $modelfinal[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($modelfinal);

Comment: That would imply that no data was added to the array. Are you sure you are adding non-empty values in your testing? This code honestly should be fine..

Comment: Okay, I think I'm onto something...I see that output...but I'm trying to add $modelfinal to an email line...the email only gives Array when it sends.

Comment: That's right, you'll have to interpret the array separately. Just adding the variable won't grab what you want. Look up on stackoverflow on how to output array data. Is your question answered, however?

Answer (score 0):

I've simulated $_REQUEST variables, but I assume your $_REQUEST variables are not arrays itself. As in your request I've imploded them to get something like **$modelfinal = "$model0, $model1, $model2, $model3, $model4";**

```
$_REQUEST['model0_is_checked'] = 1;
$_REQUEST['model1_is_checked'] = 2;
$_REQUEST['model2_is_checked'] = null;
$_REQUEST['model3_is_checked'] = 3;

$final = array();

for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
  $model_name = 'model' .$i . '_is_checked';
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$model_name]) && $_REQUEST[$model_name] != null && $_REQUEST[$model_name] != '')
    $final[] = $_REQUEST[$model_name];
}

echo implode($final, ', ');
```

this will output **1, 2, 3**

Comment: All I get is "Array" as the output: '
$model0 = $_REQUEST['model0_is_checked'];
$model1 = $_REQUEST['model1_is_checked'];
$model2 = $_REQUEST['model2_is_checked'];
$model3 = $_REQUEST['model3_is_checked'];
$model4 = $_REQUEST['model4_is_checked'];
$model5 = $_REQUEST['model5_is_checked'];

$modelfinal = array();
for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
  $model_name = 'model' .$i . '_is_checked';
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$model_name]) && $_REQUEST[$model_name] != null && $_REQUEST[$model_name] != '')
    $modelfinal[] = $_REQUEST[$model_name];
}
echo implode($modelfinal, ', ');

Comment: for loop should go till 5 if you have 5 variables. Are you sure there is at least some value in $_REQUEST. Try echoing just  $_REQUEST['model0_is_checked'] for example and see whats going on.